# How to set list data by greenDAO to many relation?

Tags: android, one-to-many, greendao

this is a example:

User and Orders.  1:N relation

but UserDAO do not have a method called "setOrders(List...)"

only getOrdersList() and resetXXXList()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to do it from the other part of the relation, Orders, using something like order.setUser(user) and updating the entity in the DB.